# OpenOffice Writer page style bug?

Tags: openoffice

I have a large Open Office odt document. It uses (mostly) four page styles: Left Page, Right Page, Left Chapter, and Right Chapter. The last two are custom styles that simply remove the header. But I have a problem with Chapter 4: if I try to set the style of the first page to Right Chapter, it sets the style of Chapter 3's first page! I've tried it several times, and it always does this. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? Or is my file corrupted?

Comment: Did you try LibreOffice? They fixed **a lot** of bugs, maybe your's is affected.

Answer (score 0):

Remember you can save the styles on an eternal file, maybe apply to a fresh document could help you debug it or find out the what exactly is going wrong.